# How to make a style affect only the child labels?

Tags: html, css

I'm starting to work with CSS and I have some problem. Surely it is very simple but, as I say, I started recently.

I have a HTML like this:

```
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div>Inicio</div>
            <div>Secciones</div>
            <div>Contacto</div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

I want it to be as in this image:

[image]

My problem is with divs elements inside the nav. 
I don't know how to give a style only to those div without modifying the html. 
My idea was to apply the style only to the child tags of a nav tag, but I have been reading about [selectors in w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and I can't find one that works for me. Some ideas?

This is for now my style for the header, but obviously it applies the style to all the divs and I don't want that:

```
header {
    background-image: url("banner.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 170px;
    width: auto;
}

nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}

div{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: `header>nav>div`??

Comment: nav > div ..... but you need to read about classes ... you need to simply read more about CSS

Comment: and why this `list-style-type: none;` on a nav ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the direct child selector

```
nav > div {
   display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change your HTML, here is the selector for your divs :

```css
header > nav > div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div>Inicio</div>
            <div>Secciones</div>
            <div>Contacto</div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

This selector means

> the direct children of nav that are divs, from the direct children of header that are nav

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple things to achieve what you want..

**1. Assign a ID or class to the nav element**

```
    <header>
        <nav id="menu">
            <div>Inicio</div>
            <div>Secciones</div>
            <div>Contacto</div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS code:

```
nav#menu div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Or if you use a class (`class="menu"`) the css will be `nav.menu div`

**2. Use the > to assign the style only to divs inside the nav element**

Just use the following CSS code which will assign the style only to childs of the navigation:

```
nav > div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Option 1 and 2 can be used together also, so for example `nav#menu > div`